# A 2D wave equation and Plot

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve and to plot a 2D wave equation:

```
weqn = D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == 
36 (D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}]);
ic = {u[x, y, 0] == x y (2 - x) (3 - y),Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, 0] == 0,u (0, y, t) == 0, u (2, 
y, t) == 0, u (x, 0, t) == 0, u (x, 3, t) == 0 };
DSolveValue[{weqn, ic}, u[x, y, t], {x, y, t}];
Plot3D[%, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 4}, Mesh -> None]
```

but I hadn't any result. Then, I need to use `Animate` with `Plot3D`.

Comment: Looks similar to [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1960607).

Comment: not the same actually, but it looks similar. I am trying to have the solution to my problem

Comment: Posted code has syntax errors. Please post syntactically correct code.

Comment: There is a [Acoustics in the time domain tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html) that is based on the wave equation. Maybe useful.

Answer (score 3):

Using Version 12.1, windows 10. Notice: V 12 unable to solve this analytically. V 12.1 is needed for analytical solution.

### Analytical solution for 2D wave PDE

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
weqn = D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == 36 Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, y}]

ic = {u[x, y, 0] == u[x, y, 0] == x y (2 - x) (3 - y),
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, 0] == 0,
   u[0, y, t] == 0,
   u[2, y, t] == 0,
   u[x, 0, t] == 0,
   u[x, 3, t] == 0};
sol = (u[x, y, t] /. First@DSolve[{weqn, ic}, u[x, y, t], {x, y, t}])[[1, 1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = Activate[sol /. Infinity -> 10]; (*10 terms is enough*)

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[sol /. t -> t0], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-2.4, 2.4}}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
  ],
 {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, .1}
 ]
```

The analytical solution is

```
sol = Inactive[Sum][(576*(-1 + (-1)^K[1])*(-1 + (-1)^K[3])*
   Cos[Pi*t*Sqrt[9*K[1]^2 + 4*K[3]^2]]*Sin[(1/2)*Pi*x*K[1]]*
   Sin[(1/3)*Pi*y*K[3]])/(Pi^6*K[1]^3*K[3]^3), {K[1], 1, Infinity}, 
  {K[3], 1, Infinity}]
```

Make sure to do `sol = sol/.Infinity->someSmallNumber` before running it.

### Numerical solution for 2D wave PDE

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

region = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}}];
region = ToElementMesh[region, MaxCellMeasure -> .05];
region["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
weqn = D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] - 36  Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 0;
bc = DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, True];
ic = {u[x, y, 0] == x y (2 - x) (3 - y), Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, 0] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{weqn, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 10}, Element[{x, y}, region]] 

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[sol[x, y, t0]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-2.4, 2.4}},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
 {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, .1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have Version 12.0, code seems doesn't work for me

Comment: @George that is correct. V 12.1 is needed.  V 12.0 can not solve this. DSolve has improved from from V 12 and now it can solve more PDE's. Alternative is to solve it using `NDSolve` in that case. But your code had `DSolve`

Comment: thanks for your response. Have you any time to help me with a numerical solve? Thank you

Comment: @George I put plain text code copy of the analytical solution, which you can copy to V 12 and use it meanwhile.